# Android : hybrid html app play mP4 video

Tags: android, html, video

I created a screen recording from my Asus Nexus 7 Tablet using adb shell command:

```
adb shell screenrecord --bit-rate 6000000 --time-limit 30 /sdcard/kitkat.mp4
```

The video was created with device in portrait mode, the detail of video are as below.

What I found is most default  Android video players were unable to play it, while some can play:

```
Asus Nexus :4.4 --> Plays Video
Asus Nexus :5.2 --> Can not play Video message
Asus Memopad 7: 4.4.2 --> Can not play Video message
```

and other most of device can not play video.

Any custom player like MX player or other video plays in all devices.

Below are video details:

```
General
Complete name                            : D:\kitkatfinal2.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom
File size                                : 1.52 MiB
Duration                                 : 17s 643ms
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 725 Kbps
Encoded date                             : UTC 2015-01-19 20:55:55
Tagged date                              : UTC 2015-01-19 20:55:55

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : Baseline@L5.0
Format settings, CABAC                   : No
Format settings, ReFrames                : 1 frame
Muxing mode                              : Container profile=High@1.3
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 17s 643ms
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 722 Kbps
Maximum bit rate                         : 6 000 Kbps
Width                                    : 1 200 pixels
Height                                   : 1 920 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 0.625
Frame rate mode                          : Variable
Frame rate                               : 13.944 fps
Original frame rate                      : 60.000 fps
Minimum frame rate                       : 0.880 fps
Maximum frame rate                       : 106.635 fps
Color space                              : YUV
```

Now basically I want to play this video from webview / Hybrid html app. I am using `Crosswalk` browser and to play video these uses a native Android video player.

How could I play the video? I thought of below cases, would any be possible?

- I can install my custom player which would server as default player for Android
- I can embed a custom player in my Hybrid Html app and video plays from there (I could not find way to use embedded player in hybrid apps)